# GPT-3 fine tuning Error: Incorrect API key provided

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm following [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PYwme_-SDOfUyg5gq7gdMuHtZMbIrcjz?usp=sharing) to fine-tune a GPT-3 model. However, when I run this part of the code:

```
# Enter credentials
%env OPENAI_API_KEY= "<MY OPENAI KEY>"
!openai api fine_tunes.create \
-t dw_train.jsonl \
-v dw_valid.jsonl \
-m $model \
--n_epochs $n_epochs \
--batch_size $batch_size \
--learning_rate_multiplier $learning_rate_multiplier \
--prompt_loss_weight $prompt_loss_weight
```

I get this error:

> Error: Incorrect API key provided:
> "sk-czja*****************************************gk0". You can find
> your API key at https://beta.openai.com. (HTTP status code: 401)

The curious thing is that the API key is correct. So much so that, if I use it to make a prompt, it works perfectly. Example:

```
def GPT_Completion(texts):
  response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt =  texts,
    temperature = 0.6,
    top_p = 1,
    max_tokens = 64,
    frequency_penalty = 0,
    presence_penalty = 0
    )
  return print(response.choices[0].text)

  GPT_Completion("My dear friend,")
```

What could be causing this error? I thought maybe the GPT-3 training could require a paid account. However, I did not find this restriction on the OpenAI website.

The whole code I'm using is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jK5LAXCaR835bBBd2S45js3_6Tir8kxE).

Comment: Try to avoid the space after "=": %env OPENAI_API_KEY="<MY OPENAI KEY>"

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution in the [OpenAI community Forum](https://community.openai.com/t/google-colab-fine-tuning-error/5917). Just `Import OS` and add this line of code:

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = <"your_api_key">
```